# How EF code first modeling will affect already existing data in database

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

Its clear to me that I can customize the behavior of syncing models and DB schema process. I am using the `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<>` class to do so.

Assume that I have a working project and site and `DB` is filling in the data. Everything is working fine.

One day I decide that some functionality needs to be changed. The changes will affect the properties of my models (they can be renamed/deleted/added, some models will be new, some models are deleted).

My question: What will happen with the already existing data on my deployed site when I check in all of my changes?

Will I lose it? If so, how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you will lose your data if your model changes and you are using `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<T>`

To avoid this:

Don't use Db initializers in production (maybe except the `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<T>`). DB initializes are there to smooth the development experience, not for production use. 
What you need is the new [Migration feature of Entity Framework 4.3.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-beta-1-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx) (currently in Beta1) which provides features for automatic and code base db schema migration.

Also now you can set the [DB initializer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-configuration-file-settings.aspx) from the `*.config` file, so you can easily switch beetween the development time `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` to no initializer in production configurations.